# My leaderboard command is not working properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried to make a leaderboard command for my discord leveling bot, but the code I have now is not working. I also doesn't produce an error. Can someone help me?

```
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx, x=10):
  with open('level.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)
  leaderboard={}
  total=[]
  for user in users:
    name = int(user)
    total_amt = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
    leaderboard[total_amt] = name
    total.append((total_amt))

  total = sorted(total,reverse=True)

  em = discord.Embed(
    title = f'Top {x} highest leveled members in {ctx.guild.id}',
    description = 'The highest leveled people in this server'
  )
  index = 1
  for amt in total:
    id_ = leaderboard[amt]
    member = client.get_user(id_)
    name = member.name
    em.add_field(name = f'{index}. {name}', value = f'{amt}', inline=False)
    if index == x:
      break
    else:
      index += 1
  await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

You guys wanted a json file, here it is.

```
{"110373943822540800": {"471602590359224351": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "81062087257755648": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "545581357812678656": {"experience": 636, "level": 5}, "535120297326805034": {"experience": 40, "level": 2}, "116138050710536192": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "152566937442975744": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "301379068941828096": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "155651120344203265": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "195156669108322313": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "435123275975360516": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "205695493395841025": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "724291966417764373": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "239809536012058625": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "186190127523954688": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "96269247411400704": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "249110399180341259": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "718444267168858175": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "406028027768733696": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "471339330212986881": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "460085286567936001": {"experience": 64, "level": 2}, "729798630483165199": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "251609977574129664": {"experience": 64, "level": 2}, "325663449680052227": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "778428586192797696": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "290570512675897345": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "287895225848954880": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "717417391293857895": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "280835732728184843": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "406713213116219403": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "199217346911404032": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "763844057205047326": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "181353804266995713": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "255114091360681986": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "267121875765821440": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "748318287892578385": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "280158289667555328": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "387062216030945281": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "190916650143318016": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "732597393446404106": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "229268431281586176": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "294544470953689088": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "423203831971708958": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "99742488666845184": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "547425603809312789": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "562415519454461962": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "737195563887624203": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "247741991310327810": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "153353572711530496": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "102528327251656704": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "87175509309419520": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "366456097839644672": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "151916651988647936": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "366649052357591044": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "753476958167367770": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "223071656510357504": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "539436493601505295": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "765917032281276426": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "190590364871032834": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "364156070475726851": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "645001499155496964": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "593776124279128084": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "712837126625951804": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "302968847353249813": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "495665367272914945": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "335490587740471297": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "518518741072347159": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "103347843934212096": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "534099893979971584": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "736926825028255744": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "594239049884237836": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "66237334693085184": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "159496406757801987": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "750938339623829606": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "380487160387731458": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "568180695151935488": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "311268449181630464": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "617675043735863327": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "699642078019452958": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "722080967421853777": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "558039389067018280": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "450052552407646218": {"experience": 64, "level": 2}, "540870950225313798": {"experience": 16, "level": 2}, "197683356643753984": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "669134055689814048": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "513792552755789825": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "710956419142254664": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "332864061496623104": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "566751683963650048": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "372851730402246667": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "311282543079063553": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "245321970760024064": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "615761944154210305": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "470432971745394688": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "467288115782877184": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "571505820261679135": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "363196037776539648": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "522232439322574860": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "526776599505403904": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "198305088203128832": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "128316294742147072": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "538762749564420096": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "503963293497425920": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "469537955569205259": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "647269760782041133": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "447538510501773325": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "261299748357668865": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "97437477723193344": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "527755176430403609": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "712323326575378562": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "326428941181124628": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "503677457107517442": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "378870718961549312": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "190544080164487168": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "485137017768771584": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "744235945389457458": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "708561286295715861": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "149505704569339904": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "528229753258246145": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "435206857276260353": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "96979199411113984": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "514800857142001686": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "455128749071925248": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "669072128922091541": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "546491068598976522": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "503215722407657478": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "554450005469954079": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "715340764485517442": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "714451348212678658": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "249430606260207617": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "721582745481904190": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "690755476555563019": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "645001123018702853": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "766412434541641780": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "386941684723744768": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "745438534650822706": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "695989173177286748": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "704468807229505637": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "475396751549792277": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "341486397917626381": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "649426958350024704": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "640987306135781398": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "448303971589685248": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "138282927502000128": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "272797713483956236": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "243728573624614912": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "656431899379499018": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "382269876456390656": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "708627584220659713": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "706874639049293924": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "748221979672445038": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "725932967754727475": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "545064119326212106": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "209769851651227648": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "686780334049984553": {"experience": 16, "level": 2}, "419958345487745035": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "779690424557109248": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "128694295170514944": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "751064521296183426": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "696900069277827092": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "700494737592942654": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "626618189450838027": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "770256654859108374": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "749387511264051223": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "732031988793606264": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "158049329150427136": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "240561665396047872": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "752996853376745472": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "628293401351159841": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "608999402744447007": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "579310061533397001": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "722363639176101949": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "323017866867900416": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "471158299681619978": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "625305547629133825": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "675593025468235806": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "713718476723978291": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "719807591869317201": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "570522126734327833": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "403475065334661130": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "743798972593864834": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "466243440758226944": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "602282653730996232": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "343491235975135243": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "568066367518015506": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "338046587337048064": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "507798218059415562": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "152810994933039104": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "325231623262044162": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "730304544101105695": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "199925219702341632": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "709643668474167348": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "314226846881284096": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "680351257277366289": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "632942579050348564": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "743387541100822598": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "707165674845241344": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "603543838681989141": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "211888560662511617": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "773600203390582814": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "98485453258240000": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "428273380844765185": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "336492042299637771": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "735631110700269659": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "702582683276017745": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "440475713523417088": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "246862123328733186": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "698478808927567942": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "662345752420417547": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "647142424333910037": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "694921610632757270": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "332196248993923073": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "607997510581092363": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "524213944043438098": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "434340890266435587": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "216925635648552960": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "715576724674314360": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "709450665696428124": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "785258015317950505": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "234464614996246529": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "170766498271461378": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "749609138249793557": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "691612324099915806": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "617761498441318458": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "716119360007176192": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "533060614713638912": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "716946043886895144": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "155867458203287552": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "560185516839141381": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "186195458182479874": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "720332581203214336": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "640975836962357261": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "178586069351137280": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}}, "770893335312465921": {"702977991353041020": {"experience": 64, "level": 2}, "681023165795008547": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "627271172509138945": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}}, "757383943116030074": {"702977991353041020": {"experience": 336, "level": 1}, "489534021290819584": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "350768528338714629": {"experience": 204, "level": 1}, "626205453793099777": {"experience": 932, "level": 1}, "704506180273438721": {"experience": 836, "level": 1}, "667110020424531994": {"experience": 1036, "level": 1}, "779170371593044000": {"experience": 304, "level": 1}, "502625636355932182": {"experience": 48, "level": 1}, "685158612871545139": {"experience": 984, "level": 1}, "549288495362080794": {"experience": 44, "level": 1}, "574999308659720213": {"experience": 216, "level": 1}, "511814805519204353": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "759578482988285963": {"experience": 56, "level": 1}, "725336588556566550": {"experience": 76, "level": 1}, "720955936268877854": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "751073327035973713": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "252882593828044800": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "545835576251777034": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}}, "716445624517656727": {"767992139850055702": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "477845082440204288": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "700812754855919667": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "579274872073486337": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "679118121943957504": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "150665783268212746": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "664242899105480715": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "712737377524777001": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "572173428086538270": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}}, "745140394370531389": {"702977991353041020": {"experience": 476, "level": 4}, "626205453793099777": {"experience": 380, "level": 4}, "414459902241538050": {"experience": 20, "level": 2}, "587418302666637312": {"experience": 112, "level": 3}, "621392786394054696": {"experience": 168, "level": 3}, "749018317653672059": {"experience": 92, "level": 3}, "385456482067415042": {"experience": 24, "level": 2}, "527305356603293709": {"experience": 48, "level": 2}, "765232264862629929": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "681023165795008547": {"experience": 16, "level": 2}, "701481986182610966": {"experience": 24, "level": 2}, "623324800164560926": {"experience": 172, "level": 3}, "675457553198612493": {"experience": 220, "level": 3}, "605507041104232449": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}}, "439866052684283905": {"582266108342566981": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "229268431281586176": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "337495178778509323": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "503963293497425920": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "547128033308442626": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "691612324099915806": {"experience": 36, "level": 2}, "750510159289254008": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "709672019842826270": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "634781586340184085": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "784803963010416641": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "707900397603258378": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "420177947652128769": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "779121240245665803": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "700812754855919667": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "732310829420118026": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "307238479564242947": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "639110055454834689": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "474422909209804807": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "399718367335940117": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "718368309896151121": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "761945664447840256": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "181605794159001601": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "784985037158088785": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "714376484139040809": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "386941684723744768": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "633779863840489484": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "314598101996535839": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "288484543080562688": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "401371734814752769": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "654546800690331682": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "626003225887375379": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "638854865854136320": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "406878868000210954": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "235243523513909249": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "361977144445763585": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "280158289667555328": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "600796140765446162": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "733060948209696819": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "147530553212534794": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "187524267355668480": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "756759522974105660": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "705659102046453770": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "536481434219708432": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "363402633752477696": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "670760037748310037": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "190590364871032834": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "701727675311587358": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "661792312673828864": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "773179581694869534": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "618431373379895306": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "511717557615722497": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "419958345487745035": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "760362839218716682": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "488411798060531732": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "623829287459487744": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "542348143379873792": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "360064639175884800": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "683323546159677441": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "778110332568600636": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "560484031838552064": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "383320268157878273": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "743828904531460186": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "650625565732241418": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "522320302680571905": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "440893159082295316": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "757103297407483986": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "640124648620818451": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "770329363915866162": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "123468845749895170": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "725297602966585374": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "610073163707056159": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "590636977100161038": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "402631938755526657": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "231733082804322304": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "677992868521967646": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "524213944043438098": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "758217390160216085": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "601799934471307268": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "297391503272050688": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "605983826115690516": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "783380853426094121": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "540870950225313798": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "734828455505690796": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "716119360007176192": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "707179585707704481": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "735295378563399711": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "765311715478601729": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "709662300721905673": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "349608447509266442": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "639564048048062507": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "526029972612055040": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "537013880224743464": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "727108703299436614": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "725071196844195970": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "625703308136546324": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "690516006749208606": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}}, "758641373074423808": {"473276250815856650": {"experience": 36, "level": 2}, "580414690472230962": {"experience": 16, "level": 2}, "705075321766150265": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "764404649465348117": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "394517700325408789": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "670684162113667092": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "638854865854136320": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "637090851943612416": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "710645707735957614": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "748318287892578385": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "490064230717063195": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "693205681238442077": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "780079091172900884": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "706610373368741889": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}}, "763008762662617148": {"720236309398159491": {"experience": 24, "level": 2}, "732967461967626340": {"experience": 40, "level": 2}, "670594516620673034": {"experience": 28, "level": 2}, "762691779514204161": {"experience": 28, "level": 2}, "720275917339099176": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}}, "768164315332214784": {"614628049283055825": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "699758096607608943": {"experience": 80, "level": 2}, "652316246737682461": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "545835576251777034": {"experience": 16, "level": 2}, "726180485021302855": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "626205453793099777": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "309652216321409025": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}}, "756108910779301908": {"441943765855240192": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "185957154606284800": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "702125603318661201": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "779733309184802836": {"experience": 56, "level": 2}, "744603004493365330": {"experience": 28, "level": 2}}, "702947765633810542": {"759914429675601920": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "564064154055344180": {"experience": 48, "level": 2}, "717597315216441395": {"experience": 32, "level": 2}, "551520654290059267": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}, "702977991353041020": {"experience": 40, "level": 2}, "699993971669073981": {"experience": 24, "level": 2}, "558029207100457000": {"experience": 52, "level": 2}, "665728255675990046": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}, "536398805336326144": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "785500654348795926": {"experience": 248, "level": 3}}, "782651282128896020": {"685158612871545139": {"experience": 12, "level": 1}}, "739736217276645388": {"732075406383120435": {"experience": 6100, "level": 8}, "717779276472254484": {"experience": 2672, "level": 7}, "732114344669741068": {"experience": 2292, "level": 6}, "731813687639146528": {"experience": 3364, "level": 7}}, "761964464488316940": {"763047922052890716": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}, "743225849679183994": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}}, "784507220015972382": {"702977991353041020": {"experience": 292, "level": 4}, "685158612871545139": {"experience": 28, "level": 2}}, "758412156487860256": {"702977991353041020": {"experience": 312, "level": 4}, "685158612871545139": {"experience": 148, "level": 3}}, "765339207622459452": {"730220061314252821": {"experience": 4, "level": 1}}, "782893136807854110": {"717779276472254484": {"experience": 344, "level": 4}, "732114344669741068": {"experience": 28, "level": 2}, "732075406383120435": {"experience": 176, "level": 3}, "731813687639146528": {"experience": 48, "level": 2}}}
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet of the json file so we can reproduce the code

Comment: In the `for user in users` loop, you try to access `user.id`, which shouldn't work. You're iterating over the keys in the `users` dictionary, and the JSON spec only allows for strings to be keys. Strings get turned into Python `str`, which has no `id` method.

Comment: do you suggest any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your query:

```py
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx, x: int=10):
    with open('level.json', 'r') as f:
        servers = json.load(f)

    leaderboard={}
    total=[]
    server = servers[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    for user in server:
      name = int(user)
      total_amt = server[user]["level"]
      leaderboard[total_amt] = name
      total.append((total_amt))

    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)

    print(total)
    em = discord.Embed(
    title = f'Top {x} highest leveled members in {ctx.guild.name}',
    description = 'The highest leveled people in this server'
    )

    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leaderboard[amt]
        
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        
        em.add_field(name = f'{index}. {name}', value = f'Level: {amt}', inline=False)
        if index == x:
          break
        else:
          index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@leaderboard.error
async def leaderboard_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please send a whole number as the number of members to display!")
    else:
        raise error
```

What my code does is that before the `for user in server` loop it defines which dictionary to go to. It goes to the dictionary of the guild that the message was sent in. Then, now that we have narrowed down the dictionary to the server that the message was in, we can start iterating through the members in that dictionary.
It iterates through every member, saves their ID as an integer string, then appends to the `total` list the level they have, and appends to the `leaderboard` dictionary the ID of the user.
After that, everything I did was a copy of yours except for the line `title = f'Top {x} highest leveled members in {ctx.guild.id}',` i changed `ctx.guild.id` to `ctx.guild.name` to tell the people the name of the guild rather than the ID.         Then, after this command, I added an error message. Basically, if someone inputs the parameter X, not as an integer, then we tell them to input an integer for X. Hope this helped! If you have any questions about this code feel free to follow up!